# Unable to look up TXT record for host Cluster0-XXXXX.mongodb.net

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXX@luster0-XXXXX.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
```

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoBootApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host Cluster0-XXXXX.mongodb.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and didn't find any relevant answers. I resolved it myself. This is the issue with your port 27017 blocked by your firewall. You need to open the outbound and inbound for this port in your firewall.

Steps for Windows:

- Go to Firewall
- Advanced Settings
- Inbound Rules
- Create a new rule with New Rule under Actions tab
- Select Port
- Select TCP and specify port no (27015,27016,27017)
- Allow the connection
- Click Next
- Add name for new Rule Finish

Follow the same steps for Outbound Rule.
Once done, restart your system.

Answer (score 3):

If you're still looking for an answer:

The issue is because some ISPs block connection string. The error will occur when using default DNS server with such ISPs.

A simple test to find out if ISP's the issue, try switching over to other network and see if it still persists.

If you're lucky and switched to an ISP which doesn't block connection string then you'll connected to your cluster. If not, you can try changing the DNS configuration to use public DNS server.

for reference: https://developers.google.com//speed/public-dns/docs/using

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cluster was paused by MongoDB Team due to the prolonged inactivity. Upon resuming it, it worked. For resuming, you go to MongoDB Atlas Cluster Dashboard, see the status and click on the Resume Cluster button.

Answer (score 0):

Your uri is: `mongodb+srv://XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXX@luster0-XXXXX.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`.

During the creation of the `Connection` there are some parts of the URI parsed. Try removing the `?retryWrites=true&w=majority` part and check whether the TXT parsing is fixed. Maybe your TXT parser doesn't recognize those options.