# Error when trying to connect Spring boot application with mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot application to MongoDB but I am getting the following error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-09-16 17:21:17.728
> ERROR 10036 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
> : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo'
> threw exception; nested exception is
> com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record
> for host simulacao.yko5j.mongodb.net  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> com.simulacao.simulacao.SimulacaoApplication.main(SimulacaoApplication.java:10)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo'
> threw exception; nested exception is
> com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record
> for host simulacao.yko5j.mongodb.net  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   ... 25 common frames
> omitted Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to
> look up TXT record for host simulacao.yko5j.mongodb.net   at
> com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:131)
> ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]   at
> com.mongodb.ConnectionString.(ConnectionString.java:378)
> ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.applyHostAndPort(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:102)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.computeClientSettings(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:70)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:61)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:57)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   ... 26 common frames
> omitted Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not
> found [response code 3]   at
> jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.checkResponseCode(DnsClient.java:664)
> ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]  at
> jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.isMatchResponse(DnsClient.java:582)
> ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]  at
> jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:430)
> ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]  at
> jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:214)
> ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]  at
> jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
> ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]  at
> jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
> ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]  at
> java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:171)
> ~[na:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:114)
> ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]   ... 36 common frames omitted

My application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://renan:masterkey@simulacao.yko5j.mongodb.net/simulacao?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.simulacao</groupId>
    <artifactId>simulacao</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simulacao</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I created the connection to the database through Atlas MongoDB.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to read that stacktrace with the current formatting. You might want to reformat it as a code snippet to get intendation and longer lines with side scrolling (makes it easier to spot actual stack trace lines).

Comment: You might need to whitelist the IP from which you are trying to connect to your MongoDB cluster. [Documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#whitelist)

Look at this [example](https://stackabuse.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial/)

Comment: Are you able to connect to the cluster from any other client programs   (e.g.,`mongo` shell or Compass)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a connection issue with the database from the error trace. Can you check if the port 27017 blocked by your firewall. You need to open the outbound and inbound for this port in your firewall.

Steps for Windows:

1. Go to Firewall
2. Advanced Settings
3. Inbound Rules
4. Create a new rule with New Rule under Actions tab
5. Select Port
6. Select TCP and specify port no (27015,27016,27017)
7. Allow the connection
8. Click Next
9. Add name for new Rule Finish
10. Follow the same steps for Outbound Rule. Once done, restart your
    system.

Comment: You should link to the source of your answer instead of copy/pasting answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61886871/2081730