# Getting DnsWithResponseCodeException and NameNotFoundException while connecting to mongo from spring boot app

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, dns

I am currently facing a weird issue. I CAN connect to the MongoDB server from MongoDB Compass and IntelliJ. But when I try to connect to the Mongo database from my Java application it continuously throws

`Caused by: com.mongodb.spi.dns.DnsWithResponseCodeException: DNS name not found [response code 3]`

`Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]`

Background:
I have a simple Java application and to run that I use Gradle's bootRun task. I have added `mongodb-driver-core`, `mongodb-driver-sync`, and `bson` dependencies from `org.mongodb` and `spring-data-mongodb` from `org.springframework.data`. I have added the connection string as a property in a yml file.

The connection string is:

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<domain>/<dbname>?ssl=false&authMechanism=PLAIN&connectTimeoutMS=30000&maxIdleTimeMS=600000`

and here is my mongo config class:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient(@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}") String url) {
        return MongoClients.create(url);

    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoClient mongo,
                                       @Value("${mongo.database}") String databaseName) {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate =  new MongoTemplate(mongo, databaseName);
        mongoTemplate.createCollection("Collection_Name");
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

The weird part is even if the application is throwing DNS name not found error, I can connect to the database from MongoDB Compass with the same connection string.

Also, one important thing to note here is the same code works for all of my teammates. They can access the database from the code.

I have tried a few things:

1. [Flush DNS](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-flush-the-dns-cache-to-improve-network-performance-in-windows-10/) cache on Windows
2. Added [inbound and outbound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927596/error-when-trying-to-connect-spring-boot-application-with-mongodb) for the port (30000 in my case) in the firewall
3. Remove the srv part from my connection URI according to the answer in [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/application-randomly-throws-failed-to-look-up-srv-record-mongodb-tcp-somedomain-pri-abcde-mongodb-net-no-such-file-or-directory/148848) post
4. Change the InterfaceMetric value of the DNS addresses according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1069163)
5. Replace my whole work laptop 2 times and this is my third laptop.

but none of them worked yet. Any help is appreciated!

Here's my complete stacktrace:

```
[INFO ] 2023-01-28 10:11:19 o.m.d.cluster [cluster-ClusterId{value='63d53b1769d90d388d824a76', description='null'}-srv-<domain>]: Exception while resolving SRV records
com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Failed looking up SRV record for '_mongodb._tcp.<domain>'.
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveHostFromSrvRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultDnsSrvRecordMonitor$DnsSrvRecordMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultDnsSrvRecordMonitor.java:80) [mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: com.mongodb.spi.dns.DnsWithResponseCodeException: DNS name not found [response code 3]
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.JndiDnsClient.getResourceRecordData(JndiDnsClient.java:52) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveHostFromSrvRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:74) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.checkResponseCode(DnsClient.java:661) ~[jdk.naming.dns:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.isMatchResponse(DnsClient.java:579) ~[jdk.naming.dns:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:427) ~[jdk.naming.dns:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:212) ~[jdk.naming.dns:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81) ~[jdk.naming.dns:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434) ~[jdk.naming.dns:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235) ~[?:?]
Caused by: com.mongodb.spi.dns.DnsWithResponseCodeException: DNS name not found [response code 3]

    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.JndiDnsClient.getResourceRecordData(JndiDnsClient.java:41) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveHostFromSrvRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:74) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
    ... 2 more
[WARN ] 2023-01-28 10:11:19 o.s.d.c.CustomConversions [main]: Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type; You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation
[WARN ] 2023-01-28 10:11:19 o.s.d.c.CustomConversions [main]: Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type; You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]
```

**Edit**: I ran the application in the debug mode and found that it uses the [loadDNSconfig0()](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/net/dns/ResolverConfigurationImpl.java#L101) native method in the loadConfig() method of ResolverConfigurationImpl.java. The loadDNSconfig0() method loads the addresses of DNS servers from the underlying OS. In the debugger window, I see the value of the "os_nameservers" property set to: “192.168.1.1 10.2.217.17,10.2.225.17 192.168.1.1”.

I tried point number 4 from above to set the InterfaceMetric values, but that didn't work.

The application runs fine when I rearrange the server addresses in the debugger window and move the DNS addresses starting with 10 (DNS set by the company's VPN) to the top of the list. With the use of the application's endpoints, I can CRUD the data to and from Mongo.

But this is just a workaround and not a final solution.

Comment: Have you tried `nslookup` for the domain of your mongodb? What does that give you? Also you might try manually adding the entry for your db in `/etc/hosts` file. See if that works.

Comment: `nslookup` for the domain returns Server, Address, and Name with their appropriate values back. I added an entry in the `hosts` file but still getting the errors.

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace from where this is occurring? If it isn't a configuration issue, then maybe something with the dependency versions or the DNS Service provider of JNDI itself.

Comment: @AritraSurRoy Added the stack trace. I doubt having issues with the dependencies (but not sure though) because the same code works on all of my teammates' ends. And I'm certain that I didn't do anything different/additional on my PC from what they did.

Comment: I believe [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/54a72fe7d3eef7378c79998a1482165f04324a87/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/internal/dns/JndiDnsClient.java#L41) is the main line in `JndiDnsClient` that's causing the exception. When it tries to resolve the DNS record for `srv` domains [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/54a72fe7d3eef7378c79998a1482165f04324a87/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/internal/dns/DefaultDnsResolver.java#L74) it fails. You can look into DNS service provider for JNDI to find the main cause of the issue.

Comment: Also check if a connection string of this format `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<domain>/<dbname>?ssl=false&authMechanism=PLAIN&connectTimeoutMS=30000&maxIdleTimeMS=600000` is able to connect to the db.

Comment: @AritraSurRoy Sorry for the late reply. I replaced my old laptop with a new one, hoping it would work if it was because of a hardware issue. But no luck there too. I am getting the same error on the new laptop. I tried removing srv part from my connection URL. That didn't work. How can I see the DNS service providers for JNDI? Could you share any link/stackoverflow answer?