# Spring Boot doesn't build with mvn

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

My Spring Boot app doesn't build with
`mvn clean install/package`
but is building with the play icon with configurations set. I need to deploy it so I need to get this JAR running.

Here are the logs that creep up when I run any of the mvn commands:

```
2021-12-06 19:05:01.848 ERROR 15837 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.8u0nj.mongodb.net
2021-12-06 19:05:01.873  INFO 15837 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-06 19:05:01.879  WARN 15837 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-12-06 19:05:01.887  INFO 15837 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-06 19:05:01.896 ERROR 15837 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at  method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.8u0nj.mongodb.net
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.8u0nj.mongodb.net
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.8u0nj.mongodb.net
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1920) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDbFactoryConfiguration.mongoDbFactory(MongoDbFactoryConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 114 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.8u0nj.mongodb.net
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.8u0nj.mongodb.net
        at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:377) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createNetworkMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.checkResponseCode(DnsClient.java:661) ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.isMatchResponse(DnsClient.java:579) ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:427) ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:212) ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81) ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434) ~[jdk.naming.dns:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        ... 144 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.876 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-06T19:05:01+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-boot-security-jwt-mongodb: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is the pom.xml of my project, do I need to add starter class in here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bezkoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-security-jwt-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-security-jwt-mongodb</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.bezkoder.spring.jwt.mongodb.SpringBootSecurityJwtMongodbApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jlefebure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-minio</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Do I need to change anything in pom.xml? My project is running fine with the configurations set in the IDE.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you are using a mixture of spring boot version. Your parent uses version 2.2.4 and some dependencies using 2.6.1 which is the first thing you should cleanup... Second the output looks like you have a test which fails...or a command you haven't showed..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to look up TXT record for host Cluster0-XXXXX.mongodb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61886714/unable-to-look-up-txt-record-for-host-cluster0-xxxxx-mongodb-net)

Comment: @tgdavies Not at all.

Comment: @khmarbaise Can I not just skip the test with `-DskipTests`? The code is running with the play button with configurations set, I can't run it with `mvn` so I can't deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Add above line in pom.xml file

then try mvn clean install, if not working then share more details about questions.

Comment: `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package` run, but I can't run the code, I can build it but can't run it.