# Unable to look up TXT record for host replica-set.xxx.mongodb.net

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am getting this error in my stacktrace of my Java Spring app:

`Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host <endpoint>.mongodb.net`

`[...]`

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]`

I can verify that I can connect to this MongoDB via Robo3T with the exact same connection string but when I run this app, I get this error.

My Spring Boot version is: `2.6.6`. And the dependency for Spring Data is: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.6.6`.

Things I've tried:

The issue I'm running into is very similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61886714/unable-to-look-up-txt-record-for-host-cluster0-xxxxx-mongodb-net). I tried updating my local Windows firewall to allow for those inbound/outbound ports (and restarted my machine) but no dice.

I then tried to update my DNS settings to use Google's 8.8.8.8 on my Windows network adapter for IPv4 but also no dice.

I also saw this fixed issue about the Java Mongo driver throwing the exact same exception above, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-4018. So I then tried to update my Spring Data Mongo dependencies to `v2.7.0` but also no dice.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd check with wireshark what and how does it query. The SO post is not relevant as firewall is global, if it works in robomongo, firewall is ok. JAVA-4018 is about ignoring NXDomain response, not related as your domain is registered.

Comment: I ran two captures, one with connect via Robo3t and the other with my java app. There are a lot of little differences but the big one (at least for me) is that on the successful robo3t connection, there's a SYN and ACK from the mongo server with a certificate, client key and encrypted handshake. Whereas the failing Java connection doesn't have that at all. I just see a few TCP packets where the mongo server isn't acknowledging back.

Comment: Is the IP *and* port number of the mongo server the same in both situations?

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't make myself clear what to look at. The mongodb+srv:// usrl must be resolved by the client to the full mongodb://host1,host2,host3, ?.... url before it even tries to connect to mongodb. To do so it connects to a **DNS** server to get the **srv** records for the mongodb+srv domain. The error arises at this stage. My guess is there are srv records but no txt ones on the domain and 3T doesn't  look for txt or ignores its absence, whilst java errors. Try `dig srv <domain>` and `dig txt <domain>`, or use `nslookup` to query these records to confirm it.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/srv-connection-strings/ have a good write-up on how it works.  Just to clarify are you using Mongodb on Atlas, or any other provider?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The IP and port numbers are not matching up between the samples. And yeah, I think you're right about the DNS type records being different - on the Java connection, it's looking for a TXT type of DNS query whereas the 3T one is looking for A type DNS queries. It also looks like on the failing Java connection, there's only one "set" of DNS packets (ie - same destination, source IP and ports) whereas 3T has two sets of DNS packets. As for the host server, my team is using a self hosted Mongo instance on-prem.

Comment: Thanks for the article. So it sounds like there is no TXT records exist for my Java app to find and it looks like I would have to create a TXT record in the DNS server? If so, is there a way I could create one with my locally? 
And correction, my team is using Mongo Atlas.

Comment: If it is atlas, it should set up both TXT and SRV records as part of provisioning the cluster.  e.g. for the connection url `mongodb+srv://<cluster_name>.<client_id>.mongodb.net/<db_name>`,   `dig txt <cluster_name>.<client_id>.mongodb.net`  returns connection parameters and   `dig srv _mongodb._tcp.<cluster_name>.<client_id>.mongodb.net`  returns list of nodes.  It won't work for self-hosted replicaset unless you set txt and srv records for your domain yourself.  Try to connect with `mongodb://` url.